# Trying to find a short sci-fi/horror story featuring another dimension with a god that feeds on pain/fear

Tags: story-identification, horror, hard-sci-fi

This is going to be a long example so bear with me.

Years ago I read a story online where an army (along with our main guy) from our dimension are sent into another to help the natives who are humanoid psychics that are physically weak by killing a being which has been attacking them. The being feeds on their pain (either pain or fear) and leaves them brain dead so they can't kill it themselves. When the army ventures into this world they come across a really out of place hotel and decide to enter one of them gets attacked by the thing and is tortured horribly, and experiences great pain in front of main guy.

Later the main guy and the rest of the army are captured by fleshy blobs with mechanical spider-like legs, captured in big nets on their underside, the main guy manages to cut himself out by stabbing the blob. He then follows the trail of the spider things to the mouth of a cave. He enters the cave (as you do), it's dark, and he has to trail his hand along the side of the cave; after a while he realizes the wall is no longer rock and is instead flesh... etc.

There's more I know but I just realized I obviously don't have to give all the story. You'd think I'd be able to find it easily considering I remember so much, but I've had no such luck :(

Also I hope this wasn't just a story I dreamt.

Please help me!
P.S. a quote from it was used on TvTropes for the first example on the Madness Mantra page

Comment: Can you please insert some line breaks, paragraphs, etc?  Walls of text like this are very hard to read.

Comment: He had carriage returns that just needed an additional Enter to turn into paragraphs. That said, @Harry, provide all of the details you can. It's even possible to add "spoilers" that need to be moused over to appear by using ">!" on blocks of text.

Comment: What quote was used?

Comment: Yes, what was the quote? The only quote I can see on the [Madness Mantra page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MadnessMantra) is from a game.

Comment: @JohnRennie yeah, it used to be the quote, but they changed it. I tried to look through the history of the page but its very unpleasant to look through.

Comment: @Richard I can't remember, I'm sorry. :S

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/article_history.php?article=Main.MadnessMantra&more=t

Comment: You might try scanning the Wayback Machine snapshots: https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MadnessMantra (but the link formatting in the comment is broken; you'll have to copy/paste the whole thing including the asterisk)